# Find documents in MongoDB with non-typical limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem, but don't have idea how to resolve it.
I've got PointValues collection in MongoDB.
*PointValue* schema has 3 parameters:

> - dataPoint (ref to `DataPoint` schema)
> - value (`Number`)
> - time (`Date`)

There is one *pointValue* for every hour (24 per day).

I have API method to get *PointValues* for specified `DataPoint` and time range. Problem is I need to limit it to max 1000 points. Typical limit(1000) method isn't good way, because I need point for whole, specified time range, with time step depends on specified time range and point values count.

So... for example:

Request data for 1 year = 1 * 365 * 24 = 8760
It should return 1000 values but approx 1 value per (24 / (1000 / 365)) = ~9 hours

I don't have idea what method i should use to filter that data in MongoDB.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampling *exactly* like that on the database would be quite hard to do and likely not very performant. But an option which gives you a *similar* result would be to use an aggregation pipeline which [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)'s the [`$first` best value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) by [`$year`, `$dayOfYear`, and `$hour` (and `$minute` and `$second` if you need smaller intervals)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). That way you can sample values by time steps, but your choices of step lengths are limited to what you have date-operators for. So "hourly" samples is easy, but "9-hourly" samples gets complicated. When this query is performance-critical and frequent, you might want to consider to create additional collections with daily, hourly, minutely etc. `DataPoint`s so you don't need to perform that aggregation on every request.

But your documents are quite lightweight due to the actual payload being in a different collection. So you might consider to get *all* the results in the requested time range and then do the skipping on the application layer. You might want to consider combining this with the above described aggregation to pre-reduce the dataset. So you could first use an aggregation-pipeline to get hourly results into the application and then skip through the result set in steps of 9 documents. Whether or not this makes sense depends on how many documents you expect.

Also remember to create a sorted index on the `time`-field.